# Attempting to place the printed statement into columns

Tags: python-3.x, typeerror

I am having trouble trying to put the output into columns. I have tried using %d but I keep getting TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting. what I have so far:

```
 ids = []
 scores = []
 grades = []
 items = []
```

## get input until stopped by 0

```
id_Test = eval(input("Enter an ID number:"))

while id_Test != 0:
    score = eval(input("Enter a score(0.0 - 100.0):"))
    ids.append(id_Test)
    scores.append(score)
    id_Test = eval(input("Enter another ID number:"))
```

## gets the average score

```
avg_score = sum(scores) / len(scores)
```

## Receives a list of scores and appends the corresponding grade 2 grades list

```
for score in scores:
    if score > avg_score + 10:
        grades.append('A')
    elif score > avg_score + 5:
        grades.append('B')
    elif score > avg_score - 5:
        grades.append('C')
    elif score > avg_score - 10:
        grades.append('D')
    else:
        grades.append('F')
```

## Headers for Columns

```
print("ID       SCORE       GRADE")
```

## Columns

```
for item in range(len(ids)):
    print('%%%8d' % (ids[item], scores[item], grades[item]))
```

I keep getting this TypeError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Ambriorix/Desktop/$RECYCLE.BIN/LAB3.py", line 40, in <module>
    print('%%%8d' % (ids[item], scores[item], grades[item]))
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```